# ¿Cómo configurar typescript para que al compilar no de errores en las rutas de los archivos importados?

Tags: javascript, typescript, modulos

Hola soy nuevo en typescript y me pasa que al momento de compilar el código a javascript genera los import de la siguiente manera:

```
import Item from "./Item";
```

Esto me genera errores ya que en javascript es necesario poner el .js y tengo que hacerlo manualmente, espero me puedan ayudar, mi archivo de configuración es el siguiente:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES6",
      "outDir": "dist",
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes encontrar más detalles sobre la configuración en la [documentación](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig). La opción que te interesa  es `module`, que es la forma en cómo son encapsulados los módulos. Debido a que el uso de `import` no fue introducido hasta ECMAScript 2015/ES6, las versiones anteriores no son compatibles con esa forma de importación. En tu archivo de configuración tienes `target: ES6` y podemos leer de la [documentación para `module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) que:

> ES6/ES2015 (synonymous, default for target ES6 and higher)

Lo que quiere decir que si utilizas un target >= ES6 entonces module será establecido a ES6/ES2015. Por otro lado tenemos que:

> CommonJS (default if target is ES3 or ES5)

Lo que quiere decir que `module: CommonJS` será utilzado cuando `target` sea ES3 o ES5.

Puede sonar confuso, pero para resumirlo de una forma simple podemos decir que la configuración `module` puede utilizar una de estas dos opciones (no son las únicas, puedes leer [este artículo](https://programacionymas.com/blog/modulos-javascript-commonjs-amd-ecmascript) en donde se explican más a detalle estos y otros sistemas de módulos):

- **CommonJS**: utiliza `require`. Valor por defecto para targets ES3 o ES5.
- **ES6+**: utiliza `import`. Valor por defecto para targets ES6+.

Y no por utilizar un target más reciente quiere decir que no puedas usar CommonJS o viceversa. Yo utilizo la siguiente configuración:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2018",
    // ...
  }
}
```

Recuerda que no existe una configuración ideal, todo dependerá de las necesidades y enfoques de tu proyecto. No tengas miedo de experimentar con las configraciones y encontrar la que mejor se ajuste a ti y a tu proyecto.